# Prestashop upload product image failed

Tags: php, prestashop

after uploading prestashop from my localhost to the server , a problem showed up
when trying to upload product image i got this error "Server file size is different from local file size"

after searching in prestashop files i found that is uploader class is responsible for the upload process.

```
public function upload($file, $dest = null)
{
    if ($this->validate($file))
    {
        if (isset($dest) && is_dir($dest))
            $file_path = $dest;
        else
            $file_path = $this->getFilePath(isset($dest) ? $dest : $file['name']);

        if ($file['tmp_name'] && is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'] ))
                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'] , $file_path);
        else
            // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
            file_put_contents($file_path, fopen('php://input', 'r'));

        $file_size = $this->_getFileSize($file_path, true);

        if ($file_size === $file['size'])
        {
            $file['save_path'] = $file_path;
        }
        else
        {
            $file['size'] = $file_size;
            unlink($file_path);
            $file['error'] = Tools::displayError('Server file size is different from local file size');
        }
    }

    return $file;
}
```

when commenting if statement witch responsible of comparing file size and tring to upload an image i got this error

"An error occurred while copying image, the file does not exist anymore."

i changed img folder permissions to 777 still same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Its a permission issue. I resolved it by giving complete access (777) to cache and theme folders.

If that doesn't help then try giving complete access to all the files. Be sure to change back the permission to 755 for folders and 644 for files for security reasons.

Answer (score -1):

please change " if ($file_size === $file['size']) " to " if ($file_size = $file['size']) "

This method worked for me.

Comment: You're assigning $file_size there, which should always return true. I don't think this does what you want it to.